# How can I improve the connection of my server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I have recently been working on a small little basic multiplayer game in pygame, and I have just recently finished the server. The problem is though with the server is that the other player's screen won't update unless the other player moves. This problem happens on the both the client and the host side of the game. Is there any way I can have my server so it will at least update on something besides just the other player's movement.

Here is the server code, and any help will be very much appreciated.

```
import socket
from _thread import *

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server = '11.0.18.15'
port = 7245

server_ip = socket.gethostbyname(server)

try:
    s.bind((server, port))

except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

s.listen(5)
print("Waiting for connection...")

currentId = "0"
pos = ["0:200,200", "1:100,100"]


def threaded_client(conn):
    global currentId, pos
    conn.send(str.encode(currentId))
    currentId = "1"
    reply = ""
    while True:
        try:
            data = conn.recv(2048)
            reply = data.decode('utf-8')
            if not data:
                conn.send(str.encode("Goodbye"))
                break
            else:
                print("Received: " + reply)
                arr = reply.split(":")
                id = int(arr[0])
                pos[id] = reply

                if id == 0: nid = 1
                if id == 1: nid = 0

                reply = pos[nid][:]
                print("Sending: " + reply)

            conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
        except:
            break
    print("Connection Closed")
    conn.close()


while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connected to: ", addr)

    start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn,))
```

Comment: Instead of using 'player' and 'other player', instead use 'player A' and 'player B' or something equally unambiguous.

Comment: I don't know want you have in client but client should periodically send request for data (even if it doesn't move) and then server should at once send answer - even if there is no data to send. And when there is no data then you should send some message - ie. `"empty"`.

Comment: network library for pygame: [Mastermind Networking Lib](http://www.pygame.org/project-Mastermind+Networking+Lib-859-.html)